# How to fill list with two columns in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have data in SQL Server database, I'm fetching data in string format.

Data looks like this:

```
08:00,11:00|11:00,13:00|13:00,16:00|
```

We see, the string is separated by commas and pipes.

Comma-separated values are Start & End Time Slots where as pipe-separated values are different time slots.

Class in C#

```
public string _TimeSlots { get; set; }  

public class TimeSlots 
{
    public string StartSlot { get; set; }
    public string EndSlot { get; set; } 
}
```

I tried this:

```
public List{TimeSlots} TimeSlotList
{
    get { return _TimeSlots.Split(',').Select(DateTime.Parse).ToList();}
    set { TimeSlots = _TimeSlots.Remove(_TimeSlots.Length - 1); }
}
```

How to fill list with two columns in C#?

Comment: The public property _TimeSlots is equal to _"08:00,11:00|11:00,13:00|13:00,16:00|"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert that string property to a List the work is more complex. You need first split on the pipe symbol, then iterate over the result and split on the comma symbol. Now you have the two elements that can be used to build a TimeSlots instance and add that instance to the list.

The work to get back a string with the specified format from a List is more simple but not as simple as you have written

```
public List<TimeSlots> TimeSlotList
{
    get
    {
        List<TimeSlots> result = new List<TimeSlots>();
        string[] parts = _TimeSlots.Split(new char[] { '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string slotData in parts)
        {
            string[] data = slotData.Split(',');
            result.Add(new TimeSlots()
            {
                StartSlot = data[0],
                EndSlot = data[1]
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
    set 
    { 
        var result = value.Select(x => x.StartSlot + "," + x.EndSlot);
        _TimeSlots = string.Join("|", result.ToArray());  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string needs to be split in the different timeslots on the pipe symbol, then each timeslot string needs splitting on the comma symbol. Then the list of timeslots can be assembled.
A Linq query will do the trick.

```
string timeSlotsString = "08:00,11:00|11:00,13:00|13:00,16:00|";
var timeSlotList = timeSlotsString.Split(new char[] { '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(slotData => slotData.Split(','))
    .Select(value => new TimeSlots() { StartSlot = value[0], EndSlot = value[1].ToString()})
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2016 then you can use string_split function like this

```
SELECT string_split(yourdatecolumn,'|')
```

If you are using older SQL Server less than 2016 then you can write your custom split function which is there in many sites.. If you require reference to that you can see one below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.split (@str varchar(max)
, @delimiter varchar(5))
RETURNS @retTable TABLE (
  id int IDENTITY (1, 1),
  splitvalue varchar(max)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @st int,
          @end int
  SET @st = 1
  SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @str)
  WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
    IF (@end = 0)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @retTable (splitvalue)
        VALUES (SUBSTRING(@str, @st, LEN(@str) - 1))
      BREAK
    END
    INSERT INTO @retTable (splitvalue)
      VALUES (SUBSTRING(@str, @st, @end - @st))
    SET @st = @end + 1
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @str, @st)
  END
  RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM split(yourdatecolumn,'|')
```